# How can i change the background colour of a webpage based on options given to the user from a select menu?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a drop down menu which allows a user to set the background colour of the webpage im making, ive searched online and only seem to find how to change the background of the actual list itself, whereas i want it to change the colour of the entire form.

Comment: You can set the color of the list? Just do that same thing to whatever other element you want. `document.body.style.background = '#000';`

Comment: that will give it a set background colour no? i need for it to dynamically change based on the colour selected from a drop down list the user picks, thanks

Comment: Right. So take the value from the selected item in the dropdown list and use that value. [Here's how to get the selected value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript). Now you've got all of the pieces you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User below select and add options as per you requirement.

```
<select id="color-select">
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

Below script is used to change background color of the webpage, you can change to a specific DOM element.

```
document.getElementById('color-select').onchange = function () {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById('color-select').value;
    };
```

Comment: thanks a million, by any chance do you know what i'd need to change to make it change the text colour of all text on the page?

Comment: Replace backgroundcolor with color

Comment: hmm doesn't seem to work, is there anything i might need to add? thanks

Comment: Add this `document.body.style.color = "#00F";` in the same go as you change the background color. Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ppuoxdtm/ Notice I based my example on @smaili 's answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example:

The HTML:

```
<body>
    <select id="color" name="color">
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

The Javascript:

```
// grab the body and select
var body = document.body;
var select = document.getElementById( 'color' );

// listen for the select's change event
select.onchange = function() {
    var color = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value; // get the selected color
    body.style.background = color; // apply the selected color to the body
};
```

Comment: I think you [need to change how you're getting the value.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: Giving this a vote even though OP is asking for changing background of page, and he explains that he already knows how to do it on the form... Consider updating your answer to work with the OP's question!

Comment: @chrisv he does say `i want it to change the colour of the entire form` so I interpreted that to be the `select`'s form :)

Comment: @smaili stupid me... I got confused of this part: "allows a user to set the background colour of the webpage im making" :P

Comment: yeah sorry, i meant i needed the entire page to change colour, thanks

Comment: @AbdellahJbari I updated it to use the `body` instead of a `form`. If this answers your question, please remember to mark it as answered.